Can I visit Czech Embassy for enquiry without any appointment?
Background of the question : I am a resident in India and I am applying for long term study visa for Czech Embassy in New Delhi.
But when I was translating my documents from English to Czech a company in India told me that I should ask my visa agent if I need to translate the documents from approved translators of Czech republic mentioned on the website here:https://seznat.justice.cz/tlumocnik?query=%7B%22filter%22%3A%7B%22druhyOsoby%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22nazev%22%3A%22%22%2C%22jazyk%22%3A%5B2%5D%2C%22vcetnePozastavenych%22%3Afalse%2C%22vcetneZaniklych%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22strankovani%22%3A%7B%22pocetNaStranku%22%3A50%7D%2C%22razeni%22%3A%7B%22hodnota%22%3A%22jmeno%22%2C%22smer%22%3A0%7D%7D. This website was given on this webpage of Czech Embassy in New Delhi: https://mzv.gov.cz/newdelhi/en/ko/visa_information/long_term_visa_long_term_residence/long_term_visa_and_long_term_residence.html . The above mentioned company warned me that if embassy doesn't accept documents from non approved translators then all my money used for translations would be wasted.
But earlier this website was very slow and I had some documents in French which I   translated and notarized in Czech by paying 450 $ to a USA based company( In hope to speed up the process of collecting all documents). When I was living in France , I translated the documents from the same group in French from English and they were valid for applying for student visa. 450$ is not a small amount in India.
My visa agent doesn't know about this , so I asked many other visa agents in the adjacent city and they also didn't knew about it as Indians rarely go to Czech Republic.
So, I have no option but to go to Czech Embassy in New Delhi for enquiry which takes 6 hours by bus.

Question: Do embassies allow visitors for enquiries without appointments since I donot have any appointment? Because otherwise 12 hours of mine will be wasted in travelling if I am not able to ask my question. It is Sunday today and I can't take any appointment today.

Kindly let me know about this if you are aware!
Thank you.

Why not ask them then? They are really the only ones that can give an authorative answer to your question.

@MarkJohnson You mean ask them by call?


when I was translating my documents from English to Czech a company in India told me that I should ask my visa agent if I need to translate the documents from approved translators of Czech republic mentioned on the website...

You should not ask your visa agent; you should first seek the information directly from the Czech government.  In fact, you probably should not be using a visa agent at all.
You certainly should reconsider giving your business to a visa agent who "doesn't know about" whether the Czech embassy will accept translations from non approved translators, because that information is freely available to anyone with an internet connection on the web page you linked to in the question:

All documents submitted along with the long-term visa/residence permit application have to be in Czech language (bank account statements may be accepted without a translation into the Czech language). All documents submitted in a foreign language must be in original and with an officially certified translation into the Czech language (the applicants are required to arrange the official translation via an official translator, the list is available here: https://seznat.justice.cz/).

(Emphasis added)
If you are willing to spend all this time and money on the visa application, it is surely better for you to spend it on dealing directly with Czech authorities rather than trying to second-guess a visa agent who seems not to be particularly interested in researching the requirements of the visa for which you are applying.

I did last time without visa agent and it was living hell.

@user fair enough. I am really somewhat baffled, however: how did you not notice that the information you were looking for was on the page you linked to, even to the point that you were considering twelve hours of travel to inquire directly at the embassy?

@user Things do tend to turn into living hell if one doesn’t read information thoroughly and carefully. Even if you use a visa agent I would still advocate that you do that, otherwise you are utterly reliant on the ability / quality of the visa agent. Plenty of questions here on TSE to show that visa agents are often not reliable, and sometimes downright incompetent.

@phoog English is not my 1st language. It is not even my 2nd language. So, you mean that I must get all the documents translated from an official translator mentioned on the website:https://seznat.justice.cz/ . Kindly confirm or deny.
